Is there any way to maintain large scale data rules efficiently in SQL?
I regularly maintain a database and conduct data audits.
Since the data is manually inputted, there are often numerous errors.
To identify and review these errors, I have implemented business data rules.
Initially, managing a small number of rules (2-3) was manageable.
However, as the number of rules increased to more than 50, I found it challenging to maintain them effectively. Can you provide suggestions on efficiently managing these data rules within SQL?
Example that I'm using:
WITH base AS
  (
  SELECT 'Apple' AS fruit, 'White' AS color, 1 as price FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple' AS fruit, 'Red' AS color, 0 as price FROM dual
  )
SELECT
  base.*,
  case when base.fruit = 'Apple' and color <> 'Red' then 1 else 0 end as wrong_color,
  case when fruit = 'Apple' and color <> 'Red' then 1 else 0 end as wrong_price
FROM base;


Use CHECK constraints, FOREIGN KEY constraints and triggers.

...and ofc , Primary Keys. And use source control

We want to build our databases such that no invalid data can be entered. For this we use tables, foreign keys, check constraints and triggers. Allowing invalid data into a database and having to check for invalid data in regular intervals sounds like a much worse approach.
Let's see what we have here...
CREATE TABLE fruit_kind
(
  id_fruit_kind  INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  kind           VARCHAR2(50), -- 'Apple', 'Banana', ...
  PRIMARY KEY (id_fruit_kind)
);

CREATE TABLE color
(
  id_color  INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  name      VARCHAR2(50), -- 'red', 'green', ...
  PRIMARY KEY (id_color)
);

CREATE TABLE fruit
(
  id_fruit       INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  id_fruit_kind  INTEGER,
  name           VARCHAR2(5), -- 'Granny Smith', 'Braeburn', ...
  id_color       INTEGER,
  price          NUMBER,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_fruit),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_fruit_kind) REFERENCES fruit_kind (id_fruit_kind),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_color) REFERENCES color (id_color)
);

Now you want to establish rules. A fruit kind can only occur in certain colors and a certain price range. Hence:
ALTER TABLE fruit_kind ADD min_price NUMBER;
ALTER TABLE fruit_kind ADD max_price NUMBER;

and
CREATE TABLE allowed_fruit_color
(
  id_fruit_kind  INTEGER,
  id_color       INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_fruit_kind, id_color),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_fruit_kind) REFERENCES fruit_kind (id_fruit_kind),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_color) REFERENCES color (id_color)
);

At last let's have a trigger to ensure correctness:
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_fruit_correctness
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON fruit
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_count INTEGER;
BEGIN
  -- Is the fruit price allowed?
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO v_count
  FROM fruit_kind
  WHERE id_fruit_kind = :new.id_fruit_kind
  AND :new.price BETWEEN min_price AND max_price;

  IF v_count = 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Price not in allowed range for this fruit type');
  END IF;

  -- Is the fruit color allowed?
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO v_count
  FROM allowed_fruit_color
  WHERE id_fruit_kind = :new.id_fruit_kind
  AND id_color = :new.id_color;

  IF v_count = 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Color not in allowed for this fruit type');
  END IF;
END trg_fruit_correctness;
/

This requires work to build it all. But with proper naming you will have a good overview. And once it is done, the basic rules are in the tables and hence easy to change. And there can be no invalid data in your database. No need to check this manually.
UPDATE: This can be better. Please read MT0's comments below.

You also need a trigger on fruit_kind so that if the min_price and max_price are updated then the fruit table is checked against the new bounds otherwise you can enter valid price data then change the min/max bounds and you find you now have invalid data that won't validate but no errors are raised because you haven't changed the fruit table. Similar for allowed_fruit_colour (and I wouldn't combine multiple checks in the same trigger - use one trigger for price and another trigger for colour).

Thinking about it, allowed_fruit_colour shouldn't be a trigger - there should be a foreign key constraint on fruit on the composite key id_fruit_kind, id_color

@MT0: Yes, you are right. Thank you.
